# Controlling various loops in the same video with javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, video, time, controls

I have a composition where keyboard events control the position of video playback. I would like to position 1 and 4 the video portion is reproduced in a loop until there is another keyboard event.

Here is the javascript I am using:

```js
    
function(__number position, __boolean reset) main(__number inputNumber[8], __number duration) {
    var result = new Object();
    var slice = duration / 8;

    if (inputNumber[0] > 0) {
        result.position = slice * 1 - slice + 1;
        result.reset = true;
    } else

    if (inputNumber[1] > 0) {
        result.position = slice * 2 - slice;
        result.reset = true;
    } else

    if (inputNumber[2] > 0) {
        result.position = slice * 3 - slice;
        result.reset = true;
    } else

    if (inputNumber[3] > 0) {
        result.position = slice * 4 - slice;
        result.reset = true;
    } else

    if (inputNumber[4] > 0) {
        result.position = slice * 5 - slice;
        result.reset = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: keyboard events = inputNumber

Comment: how is this question tagged javascript?? can someone please explain?